# How can I do a "close effect" in an image?

Tags: javascript, effect, easing, gsap

I would like to know what the name of this effect: http://www.thefeebles.com/ (hover the links on the left). They are using TweenLite, but I dont know how can i do this effect!

I tried but it's not the same: http://maiconfurtado.com.br/fabio/

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: Done! my problem was the background-position: left top. I change to right top :)

Comment: which effect in particular? There are multiple transitions used on that page. find a better example perhaps?

Comment: @neuhaus Hover over the links on the left and see the image closing and opening https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QEN7FE7f33M2FvZVlGYzVDZ3c/view

Comment: You are 2D moving the `<div>` to left and the original is applying a transition to the `width` of the `<div>` with a CSS property `float: right;` i suppose. Such as a wipe effect. (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHYg/4/) but from right).

Comment: @Redu It's only works if i remove position absolute and if i put float right, the result is the same :( removing absolute and float works from right, but from left never works

Comment: @Redu http://jsfiddle.net/tVHYg/2240/

Comment: @Redu done! my problem was the background-position: left top. I change to right top :)

Comment: OK i guess like this; http://jsfiddle.net/tVHYg/2241/